# Разбить строку по тегам и сохранить части в разные переменные

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка, части которой обрамлены в теги. Например:

```
String str = "This text is not highlighted<hlTag>but this is</hlTag>" + 
"this isn't again<hlTag>and this is</hlTag>";
```

Мне нужно распарсить ее на части — те, что внутри тегов, должны сохранятся в одни переменные, а те, что вне тегов — в другие. Результатом должен быть масив с таких объектов. При этом важно учитывать порядок частей в исходном предложении.

Должно быть как-то так: if highlighted, list.add(new HighlPart(text)), else list.add(new NonHighlPart(text)).

Я написал два регулярных выражения, для частей в тегах и вне их и они работают:

```
Matcher insideTagsMatcher = Pattern.compile(preTag + "(.+?)" + postTag).matcher(str);
Matcher outsideTagsMatcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)" + preTag +
                "|" + postTag + "(.*?)" + preTag +
                "|" + "</hlTag>(.*?)$").matcher(str);
```

Однако я не знаю, как учитывать порядок частей в исходном предложении при парсинге с помощью таких выражений. Прошу помощи.

Comment: str.split(preTag+"|"+postTag). Но это только разобьет строку на массив. Т.е. не будет явно понятно, где идет highlited, а где нет

Comment: Это понятно. Но мне нужно знать, где highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `Entry` необязательно. Можно просто создать свою обертку.

```
final static String preTag = "hlTag";

final static String postTag = "/hlTag";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "This text is not highlighted<hlTag>but this is</hlTag>" +
            "this isn't again<hlTag>and this is</hlTag>";

    String[] strings = str.split("<|>");

    //if value true - in tag, else out tag
    List<Map.Entry<String,Boolean>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean inTag = str.startsWith("<");

    for (String s: strings){

        switch (s) {
            case preTag:
                inTag = true;
                break;
            case postTag:
                inTag = false;
                break;
            default:
                result.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Boolean>(s, inTag));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]